# Logical operator "and" in python

Tags: python

Why is the self.year twice? I am having trouble to find out the logic of the line. Can some one help me with this?

```
return (self.year and self.year == date.year or True)
```

I am going through http://www.openp2p.com/pub/a/python/2004/12/02/tdd_pyunit.html and encountered the line ... And of course I have no problem understanding and, or, nor, xor, xnor, or any boolean expression. But I am confused by the way it has been used here..

:-)

Comment: [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html)

Comment: I know they are but I want to know the logic of having self.year twice. @devnull

Comment: @devnull Python 2.5 is quite old has not been actively developed for some years.  Here's the link to more recent (Py3) docs: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: Actually I am not having trouble with and & or. Have dealt with them for long time in Digital Logic. I want to know what the logic is?

Comment: This is a bit weird, the expression seems to always return `True`.

Comment: @bereal check the link i have shared. And by the way, how did you evaluate True?? Thank for your concern :D

Comment: @Nabin I checked the link. If year is not defined, it returns `True`. If year is defined, it will compare it to the `date.year` and no matter what `or` it with True. Any boolean `or`-ed with `True` is `True`.

Comment: @devnull No they haven't, its just good practice to link to the latest docs, or at least currently supported docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of evaluation matters (see [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).  The code:

```
return self.year and self.year == date.year
```

could be rewritten:

```
return self.year and (self.year == date.year)
```

Or, in full:

```
if self.year:
    if self.year == date.year:
        return True
    else:
        return False
return False # Actually return self.year, but usually a boolean is intended in this sort of situation
```

However, the expression you posted will always evaluate to `True` because of the `or True` at the end.  Using parenthesis to show evaluation order:

```
return (self.year and (self.year == date.year)) or True
```

Comment: Thank you.. I got it now.. And of course the meaning of and , or hasn't change ever.. Right? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
return (self.year and self.year == date.year or True)
```

In this case, first there is an existence check on `self.year` which will return (i assume) `None` (in python==False) if it does not exist. after that it is compared to `date.year`

I think it is a bit redundant, because the comparison would return false anyway if self.year did not exist.

As commented by Bereal on your question, the last `or True` is weird indeed, cause that seems to cause the total expression to always return `True`

general Note: In python boolean expressions are always evaluated 'in order of appearence'.

Comment: in order of appearence or there is any precedence ??

Comment: `A and B and C` is equivalent to `(A and B) and C`. 
'A==1 or 2' is not `A==(1 or 2)` but `(A==1) or 2`  efectively: always true unless `A==0`

Answer (score 1):

This line will always return true because you are doing an `or` with a true value.

Apart from that, first it checks if `self.year` is not `None` or `False`, than checks if `self.year` is equal to `date.year`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (self.year and self.year == date.year or True)
```

yes, it is required to include self.year twice. Because it will check that there is something self.year defined and if it's not defined it will give an error that there is no thing like "self.year" i.e. it's undefined. As it approves that self.year is something which is defined than it will check for it's value.